# JQuery on form submit check required fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have these JQuery functions:

```
function CheckRequired() {
    $(".required").each(function(event) {
        var check = $(this).val();

        if(check == '') {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("One or more fields cannot be blank");
            //alert($(this).attr("id"));
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").each(function() {
       $(this).submit(function(event) {
           CheckRequired();
       });
    });
});
```

so my required fields have a class of `required` but when submitting a form, its showing the `alert` error but it still submits the form

how can i stop it submitting the form if there is an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of CheckRequired() is not being returned from the submit handler.

```
return CheckRequired();
```

You might also pass the event into that function and in the case that you do not want the submit to happen, inside CheckRequired do

```
event.preventDefault();
```

I'll redo the code block...

```
function CheckRequired(event) {
    var $form = $(this);

    if ($form.find('.required').filter(function(){ return this.value === '' }).length > 0) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("One or more fields cannot be blank");
        return false;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', CheckRequired);
});
```

Comment: i tried using return `CheckRequired();` but its still submitting the form

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(event) {
     if ( !CheckRequired() ){
       event.preventDefault();
     }
  });
});
```

And I am smelling bug in the code. You are looping through each form, and for checking required you are doing a global find for `.required`

and here's the little refactor you can do to the CheckRequired function:

```
function CheckRequired() {

    var field_with_empty_ip = $(".required").filter(function(){
       return ( $(this).val() == "" );
    });

    return ( field_with_empty_ip.length < 0 );

}
```

Comment: thats correct - what would you do to not do that but still run the function as i would like to

Comment: Avoid the loop using `$('form').on('submit', function(){ /* ...*/ });` directly, since `$('form')` gets all form elements.

Comment: That's a good catch from @kmsdev. @charlie you should scope your fields inside the form. I mean ideally, when a form gets submitted, you should look for `.required` fields inside that form not everywhere.

Comment: this is still submitting the form even when their are black fields that are required

Comment: There was a mistake at return statement in CheckRequired(). I have fixed and refactored the code.